# angularjs, needs to make json object property values in string format to be rendered as actual templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-templates

I have the following json array of which each object is accessed  on a specific tab click. Each json object of the array has different templates like they can represent ui-grid, or c3 chart directive (c3.js), etc

Now when the user clicks specific tab, this template which is currently in in string format needs to be made to render actual templates like ui-grid, c3-chart, etc

```
var sampleJsonArray = [{
        id: 0,
        tabName: "Table",
        template: '   <div id="queryListGrid" ui-grid="queryListGridOptions" class="grid query-list-grid"></div>'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        tabName: "Cost - Line",
        template: ' <c3-simple id="view1" config="c3ChartCost"></c3-simple> '
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        tabName: "Spend - Bar",
        template: ' <c3-simple id="view2" config="c3ChartSpend"></c3-simple> '
    },
];
```

The following are each tabs templates sample jsons:

```
    $scope.queryListGridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        columnDefs: [{
                field: 'name'
            },
            {
                field: 'gender'
            },
            {
                field: 'company',
                enableSorting: false
            }
        ],
        data: //data will be fetched from http call -- []
            onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
                $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
            }
    };

$scope.c3ChartCost = {
    size: {
        height: 250,
        width: 200
    },
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
        ],
        type: 'line'
    }
};
$scope.c3ChartSpend = {
    size: {
        height: 250,
        width: 200
    },
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 5, 510, 160, 700, 190, 960],
            ['data2', 87, 450, 56, 780, 670, 890]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use `$sce` service provided by angular. Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) is a mode in which AngularJS requires bindings in certain contexts to result in a value that is marked as safe to use for that context.
 I dont have much time to provide you with a working code snippet right now. Checkout this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) from angular. Let me know if you need any help later.